# How to do UIkit slider center mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, uikit

I'am trying to look my Uikit slider like this for about 4 hours now...
[image]
Can someone help me with it? I ran out of ideas

Here is my code:

```
<div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" tabindex="-1" uk-slider="center: true">

<ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-3">
    <li>
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="">
    </li>    
    
</ul>

<a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
<a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>
```

p.s. I can't use jquery

Comment: What is the problem exactly with what you have currently? The problem is easier to solve on here if you create an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden the problem is than I can't style center slide, cuz all three slides have active class at the same time. I just don't know how can I style only one active which is in the center of viewport

Answer (score 0):

If still relevant

```
li.uk-active:nth-child(2) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.uk-slider-items li:nth-of-type(2) {}
```